# Would prefer + to-gerund

Tags: modal-verbs, gerunds, to-infinitive

We can say

> I prefer going to the cinema.

and

> I prefer to go to the cinema.

But can we say

> I would prefer to go to the cinema

and

> I would prefer going to the cinema
>   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, your two **would** sentences are **grammatical and understandable**.
**Would** is used as an **auxiliary verb**
Using **would** makes it a **polite request**